# Can you extract issues from Jira on premise for reporting to management?

Tags: jira, reporting

We have had a lot of success using JIRA for our risks, issues, decisions and milestones. What I want to do, though, is to have these queried and represented on a dashboard with Gantt charts, issue severity etc.

Is there a way to extract these from JIRA's on-premise instance?

Comment: Does the dashboard exist within JIRA or are you looking to export the data into a PDF type of report?

Comment: Check JIRA Structure plugin. That might be what you need.

Comment: There are great reporting plugins on Atlassian market, you should choose one best suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

JIRA can export data in the following formats:

1. As an XML dump

For example, here are the steps to export to Wordpress:

```
1. Install the [RSS Widget](https://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/rss-widget/) in WordPress

2. Create a filter in JIRA and share it

3. In the filter screen Export>RSS (issues) and right click to copy the URL

4. Go to the WordPress RSS Widget and add the RSS URL and the username and password:

https://jirainstance.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-rss/XXXXX/SearchRequest-XXXXX.xml?tempMax=10&os_username=uxwpuser&os_password=uxwppassword

Where:

tempMax = n -> n is the total issues you want to display in the widget

&os_username=uxwpuser&os_password=uxwppassword is the section you need to add at the end of the URL's

XXXXX is the filter ID in JIRA
```

2. Export to Excel:

[image: JIRA Export to Excel link]

**References**

- [Solved: How can one post JIRA reports in WordPress instances](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-can-one-post-JIRA-reports-in-WordPress-instance/qaq-p/46035)
- [Export More than 1000 Issues to Excel from Issue Navigator in JIRA](https://mraddon.blog/2016/04/14/export-more-than-1000-issues-to-excel-from-issue-navigator-in-jira/)
- [Atlassian Community - Solved: How to do pagination on JIRA Rest api?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-do-pagination-on-JIRA-Rest-api/qaq-p/516052)